# Eliminar variables duplicadas en rstudio según criterio

Tags: r, rstudio, eliminar-duplicados

tengo una variable llamada "var1" que tiene una serie de casos duplicados y necesito compararlo entre ellos, dejando aquel que tenga la fecha más reciente (variable llamada "fecha".
Por ejemplo:

```
|var1  | tiempo |
juan1  | 60          
juan1  | 73      
juan1  | 55
maria1 | 55     
maria1 | 100
jose1  | 15
jose1  | 33
jose1  | 35
```

Y necesito que quede así

```
|var1  | tiempo |
juan1  | 73 
maria1 | 100
jose1  | 35
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés agrupar por `var1` y luego extraer las fechas más reciente usando `slice_max`, el argumento `with_ties = FALSE` es para que no retorne valores repetidos, sólo tome el primer resultado.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(var1) %>% 
  slice_max(tiempo, with_ties = FALSE)

    var1      tiempo
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 "jose1  "     35
2 "juan1  "     73
3 "maria1 "    100
```

Sólo por temas estéticos, este código remueve los espacios al final de cada nombre

```
df %>% 
   group_by(var1) %>% 
   slice_max(tiempo, with_ties = FALSE)  %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   mutate(var1 = trimws(var1))
 
  var1   tiempo
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 jose1      35
2 juan1      73
3 maria1    100
```

Comment: No me sirve ese código porque tengo muchos casos duplicados (+15.000) y necesito que compare entre los casos que se encuentran duplicados, cual de ellos es el mayor.
No solo tengo a juan1 repetido 3 veces, si no que también necesito que compare a Maria1, Jose1, etc. Todos esos datos también están repetidos X cantidad de veces

Comment: @Catalina, he actualizado mi respuesta y con ese código se consigue el resultado buscado

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa con R base

Primero usamos `aggregate()` para agrupar por `Var1` y ver cuales son los  máximos por grupo

```
recuento <- aggregate(tiempo ~ var1, df, max)
recuento

    var1 tiempo
1  jose1     35
2  juan1     73
3 maria1    100
```

Luego unimos este recuento con el `data.frame` original:

```
subset(merge(df, 
             recuento, 
             by="var1", 
             all.x = TRUE, 
             suffixes=c("", ".y")), 
       tiempo == tiempo.y)[, c('var1', 'tiempo')]

    var1 tiempo
3  jose1     35
5  juan1     73
8 maria1    100
```